# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; Creating table no obvious errors (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having some issues with MYSQL, and cannot find any solution. I'm new to SQL and so I'm not sure this is right, but someone more experienced said this should work fine?

I'm using PHP version: 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: b5c5906d452ec590732a93b051f3827e02749b83 $

```
CREATE TABLE playerdata('SteamID' VARCHAR NOT NULL, 'Money' INT, PRIMARY KEY('id'));
```

Thanks. Conn

Comment: MySQL != SQL-Server

Comment: Well....you are trying to set your primary key to a column that doesn't exist.

Comment: Even so,     CREATE TABLE playerdata('id' INT, 'SteamID' VARCHAR NOT NULL, 'Money' INT, PRIMARY KEY('id')); still fires the same error

Comment: What kind of SQL are we talking about? Hint: it's *either* MySQL *or* SQL Server.

Comment: MySQL, should have put originally.